# Yii 2.0 change default controller

Tags: yii, controller, yii2

How in Yii 2.0 basic framework can change default controller?
In default it is set to load 'site' controller, but I need to load custom controller by default. 
Where can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

Use this configuration

```
'defaultRoute' => 'myController/myAction',
```

Comment: Where should this be added?

Comment: in config/web.php under $config array

Answer (score 0):

`{'defaultRoute' => 'myController/myAction'}`, is absolutely correct. 
Just for example: `{'defaultRoute' => 'site/login'}` where 'site' is name of controller & 'login' is action.

Answer (score -1):

Use this configuration

```
'defaultRoute' => 'myController',
```

For example:

```
'defaultRoute' => 'login',
```